# Using zorn's lemma to prove aleph 0 is the least infinite cardinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand zorn's lemma, but it is confusing me on how to apply it to an infinite set.

I am asked to prove that if A is an infinite set, then there exists an injection from $\mathbb{N}$->A using Zorn's lemma.

The proof is easy using the axiom of choice, but I cannot figure out how to ensure that the set is always partially ordered and every totally ordered subset has an upper bound.
Thank you

Comment: each function from $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$ has a subset of $A$ as its image.  How do you partially order subsets of $A$?  What is the largest subset of $A$ (ordered by inclusion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all injective functions $f$ such that $f$ has domain a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, and $f$ has codomain $A$.

For any two such functions $f$ and $g$, write $f\lt g$ if the domain $D_f$ of $f$ is a subset of the domain $D_g$ of $g$, and $g$ restricted to $D_f$ is $f$.

Note that any chain in $\mathbb{F}$ has an upper bound.

Comment: Is the fact that any chain has an upper bound because dom(f) has an upper bound of N?

Comment: You can give the upper bound explicitly. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a chain. Let $F$ be the "union" of the functions in the chain. So for any $n$ such that $n$ is in the domain of some function $f$ in the chain, let $F(n)=f(n)$. Because $\mathcal{C}$ is a chain, $F(n)$ does not depend on the $f$ we used.

Comment: Okay that all makes sense! Thank you, so then from here we just define some function h:N->a defined by h(a)=max(F-{h(0),...,h(a)})?

Comment: Every chain has an upper bound, so $\mathcal{F}$ has a maximal element $G$. Let $M$ be the domain of $G$. If $M$ is not all of $\mathbb{N}$, and $A$ is not the range of $G$, we can extend $G$ by adding an element to the domain, contradicting maximality. So we can assume that $G$ has range $A$. Since $A$ is not finite, the domain of $G$ is infinite. Then $G$ can be modified to give a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the collection of finite subsets of $A$. If it has a maximal element, then $A$ must be finite, therefore there exists a chain without an upper bound. Therefore it must be infinite (as finite chains has a maximal element which is a bound).

Note that Zorn's lemma proves, quite easily, that every chain can be extended to a maximal chain. So we may assume that this chain is a maximal chain.

But this chain is a chain of finite subsets of $A$, each cardinality appearing in this chain is distinct. By maximality we have that every finite cardinality appears in that chain exactly once.

Write $A_n$ for the unique set of size $n$ in this chain, can you come up with an injection from $\Bbb N$ into $\bigcup A_n$?

Comment: Why can we assume that the chain is maximal?

Comment: @Andres: Because Zorn's lemma proves (quite easily, too) that every chain can be extended to a maximal chain.

Comment: But if we are going to do that, why not directly use it with a chain of partial injections? It seems you are working twice as hard as it is needed.

Comment: @Andres: Because Andre already suggested that. :-)

Comment: Sure. Anyway, the real point of the comment is that you may want to make explicit that the key assumption is hidden in that sentence. (I think it is better to err on the side of being too explicit.)

Comment: I generally agree with you. (I know some that will agree more than just generally, and I know some that will definitely disagree. And I know some that will consider it on a case per case basis.)